# Can an Ethernet-connection be made without lo interface?

Tags: networking, ethernet

I am running Linux on laptop with active ufw and Ethernet-connection.

```
netstat -tuplna
```

tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:53            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -

After the lo interface is down by:

```
sudo ifconfig lo 127.0.0.1 down
```

the internet-connection by browser is impossible.

I was thinking that the lo interface is used just for troubleshooting and the internet-connection is provided not by lo but by eth0 interface.

Now it appears that the lo interface is an integral part of the Ethernet-connection and without it there is no internet-connection.

Can an Ethernet-connection be made without lo interface?

What role the lo interface plays in an Ethernet-connection?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it can. `lo` is just a local interface.

But you have your resolver pointing to 127.0.0.1, so, if you bring it down then you will not be able to resolve anymore, but you could `ping 1.1.1.1` for example.

Comment: How could I make my resolver to point not to 127.0.0.1 but to some other IP which will allow me to resolve DNS domains when lo interface is down?

Comment: @ccsann Google "My_OS_name how to change DNS server"

Comment: Why do you want to bring `lo` down? While you technically can do it, it is also used by other applications.